# Webbrowser How Can i Getting Dynamic Created Elements

Tags: javascript, c#, html

My english not good, please basic english for answers thanks.

İ want to make basic c# program for posting some forms. this is example.

This is page source code :

```
<form>
  <input type='text' id='username' name='username'>
  <input type='password' id='password' name='password'>
  <input type='submit' id='login_button' value='login'>
</form>
```

My program auto fill this inputs and click submit button everythink is okey.

But sometimes clicking login button form creating dynamic captcha in div.
i cant get div attributes on webbrowser.
This is page source code :
Example With Dynamic Created Div:

```
<form>
  <input type='text' id='username' name='username'>   
  <input type='password' id='password' name='password'>
```

/*Dynamic Created Div Start*/

```
<div class="captcha-item" id="recaptcha_image" style="width: 300px; height: 57px;">
<img style="display:block;" alt="reCAPTCHA sorusu resmi" height="57" width="300" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VusAFaZS5rvfB19q2Emz-7XuayLW3r5OcGO7zzwFrSWoDeaDNRBo1B7lGVTfInKsVP3RBhg_P7_pRhMIajud1GosuIseTrg8C-z8mh2CY_BOiDIj4subsjD3kWP7wk6evBTHxzfOn7ryQrv4aChE9dMy0krKNxl9QbGvMcd43Ig83F22OBViLTITiL9GgpHBNF4M6B0Ja7bg0EGLHxCc-AQIWhtd1A_Mm_A3bgdPg_DzVbTDS3qIRcxbYqJSj3lKHcOYuPSIeCDPfE6773Q8O2utZTx1SA"></div>
```

/*Dynamic Created Div End*/

```
<input type='submit' id='login_button' value='login'>
</form>
```

how can i get dynamic created element's attributes with c# webbrowser ?